# SQL - different Id with same value then True without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to transform following table without a subquery:

```
Document     Reader 
doc1         John
doc2         Max
doc2         John
```

This would be my desired result :

```
Reader      Duplicate
John        True
Max         False
```

Comment: `COUNT` and `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by to get the readers distinct, and count in a case to determine they are duplicate

```
declare @t table (Document varchar(10), Reader varchar(10))
insert into @t values ('doc1', 'John'), ('doc2', 'Max'), ('doc2', 'John')

select t.Reader, 
       case when count(Document) > 1 then 'True' else 'False' end as Duplicate
from   @t t
group by t.Reader
```

And if you need Duplicate as a bit column, than use this

```
select t.Reader, 
       convert(bit, case when count(Document) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Duplicate
from   @t t
group by t.Reader
```

You can try it out yourself in [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0852ed8c285fb92a90dc26e2cc2d35ba)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Reader, CASE WHEN COUNT(Reader)>1 Then 'True' Else 'False' END Duplicate 
FROM <your_table>
Group By Reader;
```